# Why css class on table cell is not prioritized?

Tags: html, css

```
<table id="table1">
    <colgroup><col><col><col><col></colgroup>    
    <tr><th class="green">th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</th><th>th4</th> </tr>
    <tr><td class="green">Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="green">Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="green">Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="green">Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#table1 {width:100%; table-layout:fixed;}
#table1 td, #table1 th{border:1px solid; background-color:yellow;}
.green {background-color:green;}
```

I am trying to avoid !important on class .green, because i would have to write many of those on my webpage, and i read it's bad practice. http://jsfiddle.net/y3cnc0ty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to CSS "Specificity". There's an order of precedence for CSS selectors, and ID is more important than CLASS.
You can read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

You could overcome this with

```
#table1 .green {background-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

## table1 tr td.green {background-color:green;}

I am not sure but I believe since you've used a deep reference for yellow bg, you need a similar or deeper reference for an element nested inside.